# Bash .profile not loading

Tags: macos, bash

I'm not sure what's happened but my ~/.profile is no longer loading.

Can anyone see something wrong with the following?

```
export PS1="\u@local [\w]# "
export EDITOR="subl -w"
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias vst="ssh -i ~/.ssh/vst root@vst"
```

I know for a fact using that PS1 like I am attempting to do it should be doing `Peter@local [~/path/to/file]#` but it's not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Does `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exist?  If so, that'll be used instead of `~/.profile`.

Comment: I did in fact have a `.bash_login`. Copying the contents from there to .profile and removing bash_login fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter: the solution kenorb gave below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29152555/499797) is a much better than copy pasting all information into the same file.

Comment: Stumbled on this thread when reverting from Mac OSX Catalina "upgrade" of zsh back to bash. Turns out ~/.bash_profile isn't used, and only ~/.profile is being sourced when using /bin/sh as default terminal now. Copy bash_profile to profile and your old sources will be available.

Answer (score 30):

In [Unix FAQ (for OS X)](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup) we can read:

> **Bash Startup Files**
>
> When a "login shell" starts up, it reads the file
>   `/etc/profile` and then `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or
>   `~/.profile` (**whichever one exists - it only reads ONE of these**,
>   checking for them in the order mentioned).
>
> When a "non-login shell" starts up, it reads the file `/etc/bashrc` and then the file `~/.bashrc`.
>
> Note that when bash is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup sequence of the Bourne shell (`sh`). In particular, **a non-login shell invoked as `sh` does not read any dot files by default**. See the bash man page for details.

So if you already have `~/.bash_profile`, the file `~/.profile` won't be automatically read by bash, therefore you can add the following lines in your `~/.bash_profile` to load it:

```
# Load user profile file
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi
```